# how to allow the user to choose how to sort his list using a variable?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

the information that the user enters can be sorted in many ways ascending and descending and i'm trying to make the user choose how he want to see the data:

so is there any way to set a variable that the user enter and sort the data without repeating the code multiple time depending on the input like:

```
var empName = el.Select(i => new { i.ID, i.FullName });
    if(emsort.Text="text1")
    empName.OrderBy(i.text1);
else if...
```

by doing something shorter like:

```
 string sort=emsort.Text ;
empName.OrderBy(sort);
```

Comment: We have no idea what `i` or `empName` are...or anything really. Look at reflection maybe.

Comment: you apparently saving the sorting info in database, retrieving it in `emsort` object, and want to pass the sort field to the `OrderBy` method to tell which property to sort by, you might consider reflection, but it's not recommended unless you have so many sortable fields

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic LINQ OrderBy on IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet)

Comment: is it better now ? do you know what i and empName are now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the *User* in your question is some software that calls your function, then the user is aware of the type of the objects in the `el` sequence: he knows which properties the elements in the `el` sequence are, and he knows how he wants them ordered.

Why not let this user give you the `keySelector` to use in the OrderBy?

Creating an extension function:

```
static class QueryableExtensions
{
    IQueryable<MyType> SelectAndSort<TSource, TResult>(this IQueryable<TSource source,
        Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> selector, 
        Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> sortKeySelector,
        System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection sortDirection)
    {
        var selectBeforeOrdering = myRepository.el.Select(selector);
        // note: this is still an IQueryable, only the query has been made,
        // the database is not accessed yet!

        IQueryable<TResult> result = (sortDirection == ListSortDirectrion.Ascending) ?
            // sort in ascending order:
            selectBeforeOrdering.OrderBy(sortKeySelector) :
            // else: selec in descending order:
            selectBeforeOrdering.OrderByDescending(sortKeySelector);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Usage: suppose your user knows your `el`, and he want several fields of it, ordered by one of the properties of your `el`

```
using (var myDbContext = new DbContext(...))
{
    IQueryable myEls = myDbContext.el;

    var mySelectedItems = myEls.SelectAndSore(
        // selector: what properties do I as a user want?
        el => new
        {
             Id = el.Id,
             FullName = el.FullName,
             ... // other desired properties
        },
        // sortSelector: how do I want my selected items to be sorted?
        selectedItem => selectedItem.FullName,
        // direction:
        ListSortDirection.Descending);

        // note: until now the database has not been accessed
        // only the Expression of the query has been created.

        // depending on what you want as a result: ToList / ToArray / First / ...
        return mySelectedItems.ToList();
    }
```

If, on the other hand your user is not software, but an operator, who has to select by which column he wants his items to be ordered, he has to have a method to tell the computer which column should be sorted.

This is usually done by clicking the column. Another method could be by selecting a value in a combo box. Anyway, you'll have to attach something to the column or to the combobox values that holds the sortKeySelector:

```
class MySortableColumn<TDisplayedProperty> : DataGridViewColumn 
   // or whatever column class you are using
{
    public Expression<Func<MyDisplayedItem, TDisplayedProperty>> SortKeySelector{get;set;}
}
```

Now you have several columns that each display one of the properties of MyDisplayedItem:

```
var columnId = new MySortableColumn<int>()
{
    SortKeySelector = displayedItem => myDisplayedItem.Id,
};
var columnFullName = new MyStortableColumn<string>()
{
    SortKeySelector = displayedItem => myDisplayedItem.Id,
}
// etc.
```

Whenever the operator clicks on a column, the sortKey is extracted and used as parameter to sort the items:

```
void SortColumn(SortableColumn column)
{
     var sortedItems = Sort(column.SortKeySelector, ListSortOrder...);
     Display(sortedItems);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your problem right, that you want to sort dynamically with the property name which is stored in `emsort.Text`, then you can use Expressions:

assuming `empName` is `IEnumerable<Employee>`, then use this:

```
private static Func<Employee, dynamic> GetSortable(string sortablePoperty)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Employee), "e");
        var member = Expression.Property(param, sortablePoperty);
        Expression memberAsObject = Expression.Convert(member, typeof(object));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<Employee, dynamic>>(memberAsObject, param).Compile();
    }
```

then use it:

```
string sort=emsort.Text ;
empName.OrderBy(GetSortable(sort));
```

if `empName` is `IQueryable<Employee>`, then use this:

```
private static Expression<Func<Employee, dynamic>> GetSortable(string sortablePoperty)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Employee), "e");
        var member = Expression.Property(param, sortablePoperty);
        Expression memberAsObject = Expression.Convert(member, typeof(object));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<Employee, dynamic>>(memberAsObject, param);
    }
```

Comment: i guess this is the answer but  i can't use it cause we can't use codes that we haven't been taught, so i'll go through the whole process of ifs and elses

Answer (score 1):

As I assume, `el` is materialized(i.e., for example, it is not just entry point to database), so you can use reflection:

```
var sort = emsort.Text;
PropertyInfo property = null;
var sortedData = el.Select(i => new { i.ID, i.FullName })
     .OrderBy(x => 
     {
          property = property ?? x.GetType().GetProperty(sort);
          return property.GetValue(x);
     }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a part of the code that i had to write to do it :

```
if (emord.Text == "Ascending")
        {

            if (emsort.Text == "ID")
            {
                var empName = el.Select(i => new { i.ID, i.FullName }).OrderBy(x => x.ID);
                var empNamenAmp = el.Select(i => new { i.ID, i.FullName, i.Salary, i.Currency, i.Per }).OrderBy(x => x.ID);
                var empNamenAmpnwh = el.Select(i => new { i.ID, i.FullName, i.Salary, i.Currency, i.Per, i.Hours }).OrderBy(x => x.ID);
                var empNamenwh = el.Select(i => new { i.ID, i.FullName, i.Hours }).OrderBy(x => x.ID);
                var empNamenbd = el.Select(i => new { i.ID, i.FullName, i.Date }).OrderBy(x => x.ID);
                var empNamenad = el.Select(i => new { i.ID, i.FullName, i.Location }).OrderBy(x => x.ID);
                var empNamenpn = el.Select(i => new { i.ID, i.FullName, i.PhoneNb }).OrderBy(x => x.ID);
                var empNamena = el.Select(i => new { i.ID, i.FullName, i.Age }).OrderBy(x => x.ID);
                if (empfilcomb.Text == "Name")
                {
                    dispfil.Clear();
                    foreach (var x in empName)
                        dispfil.Text += x.ID + ", " + x.FullName + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                else if (empfilcomb.Text == "Name and Amount paid")
                {
                    dispfil.Clear();
                    foreach (var x in empNamenAmp)
                        dispfil.Text += x.ID + ", " + x.FullName + ", " + x.Salary + " " + x.Currency + " " + x.Per + Environment.NewLine;
                }

                else if (empfilcomb.Text == "Name and Work Hours")
                {
                    dispfil.Clear();
                    foreach (var x in empNamenwh)
                        dispfil.Text += x.ID + ", " + x.FullName + ", " + x.Hours + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                else if (empfilcomb.Text == "Name,Amount paid and Work Hours")
                {
                    dispfil.Clear();
                    foreach (var x in empNamenAmpnwh)
                        dispfil.Text += x.ID + ", " + x.FullName + ", " + x.Salary + " " + x.Currency + " " + x.Per + ", " + x.Hours + Environment.NewLine;

                }
                else if (empfilcomb.Text == "Name and Birthday")
                {
                    dispfil.Clear();
                    foreach (var x in empNamenbd)
                        dispfil.Text += x.ID + ", " + x.FullName + ", " + x.Date + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                else if (empfilcomb.Text == "Name and Address")
                {
                    dispfil.Clear();
                    foreach (var x in empNamenad)
                        dispfil.Text += x.ID + ", " + x.FullName + ", " + x.Location + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                else if (empfilcomb.Text == "Name and Phone Number")
                {
                    dispfil.Clear();
                    foreach (var x in empNamenpn)
                        dispfil.Text += x.ID + ", " + x.FullName + ", " + x.PhoneNb + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                else if (empfilcomb.Text == "Name and Age")
                {
                    dispfil.Clear();
                    foreach (var x in empNamena)
                        dispfil.Text += x.ID + ", " + x.FullName + ", " + x.Age + Environment.NewLine;

                }
            }
            else if (emsort.Text == "Name")
            {
                var empName = el.Select(i => new { i.ID, i.FullName }).OrderBy(x => x.FullName);
                var empNamenAmp = el.Select(i => new { i.ID, i.FullName, i.Salary, i.Currency, i.Per }).OrderBy(x => x.FullName);
                var empNamenAmpnwh = el.Select(i => new { i.ID, i.FullName, i.Salary, i.Currency, i.Per, i.Hours }).OrderBy(x => x.FullName);
                var empNamenwh = el.Select(i => new { i.ID, i.FullName, i.Hours }).OrderBy(x => x.FullName);
                var empNamenbd = el.Select(i => new { i.ID, i.FullName, i.Date }).OrderBy(x => x.FullName);
                var empNamenad = el.Select(i => new { i.ID, i.FullName, i.Location }).OrderBy(x => x.FullName);
                var empNamenpn = el.Select(i => new { i.ID, i.FullName, i.PhoneNb }).OrderBy(x => x.FullName);
                var empNamena = el.Select(i => new { i.ID, i.FullName, i.Age }).OrderBy(x => x.FullName);
                if (empfilcomb.Text == "Name")
                {
                    dispfil.Clear();
                    foreach (var x in empName)
                        dispfil.Text += x.ID + ", " + x.FullName + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                else if (empfilcomb.Text == "Name and Amount paid")
                {
                    dispfil.Clear();
                    foreach (var x in empNamenAmp)
                        dispfil.Text += x.ID + ", " + x.FullName + ", " + x.Salary + " " + x.Currency + " " + x.Per + Environment.NewLine;
                }

                else if (empfilcomb.Text == "Name and Work Hours")
                {
                    dispfil.Clear();
                    foreach (var x in empNamenwh)
                        dispfil.Text += x.ID + ", " + x.FullName + ", " + x.Hours + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                else if (empfilcomb.Text == "Name,Amount paid and Work Hours")
                {
                    dispfil.Clear();
                    foreach (var x in empNamenAmpnwh)
                        dispfil.Text += x.ID + ", " + x.FullName + ", " + x.Salary + " " + x.Currency + " " + x.Per + ", " + x.Hours + Environment.NewLine;

                }
                else if (empfilcomb.Text == "Name and Birthday")
                {
                    dispfil.Clear();
                    foreach (var x in empNamenbd)
                        dispfil.Text += x.ID + ", " + x.FullName + ", " + x.Date + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                else if (empfilcomb.Text == "Name and Address")
                {
                    dispfil.Clear();
                    foreach (var x in empNamenad)
                        dispfil.Text += x.ID + ", " + x.FullName + ", " + x.Location + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                else if (empfilcomb.Text == "Name and Phone Number")
                {
                    dispfil.Clear();
                    foreach (var x in empNamenpn)
                        dispfil.Text += x.ID + ", " + x.FullName + ", " + x.PhoneNb + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                else if (empfilcomb.Text == "Name and Age")
                {
                    dispfil.Clear();
                    foreach (var x in empNamena)
                        dispfil.Text += x.ID + ", " + x.FullName + ", " + x.Age + Environment.NewLine;

                }
            }
```

and i was asking if there is a shorter way to do it:withing what i'm allowed to use. Seems that there isn't but thanks a lot for the help i'm sure what you guys provided is useful.